# Event for when state is set

Tags: reactjs, state

In React the `this.setState` method sets state. For instance below I set the state for `name` to `Thomas`.

```
this.setState({'name': 'Thomas'})
```

I need another object. A state property that comprises of other state properties. For instance below.

```
let name = 'Thomas'
this.setState({name})

console.log(this.state.data) // => undefined

let age = '26'
let data = {age}
this.setState(data)

console.log(this.state.data) {data: {age: '26'}}

this.stateChanged(state => {
  let data = state.data || {}
  if (state.name) data.name = state.name
  this.setState({data})
})

this.setState({name})

console.log(this.state.data) // => {data: {age: '26', name: 'Thomas'}}
```

Is there any equivalent `this.stateChanged` method in React?

Comment: Usually, you only care about state changes for `render` which is rerun on state changes. If you care about it for another reason, trying to shoehorn that need into a React view component may or may not be a good way to go (I'd assume not a good way but not judging as I don't know the context).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React gives us a couple explicit options to determine when the state's changed, or component has been updated. The third option being more of an implicit approach for your particular case:

1. Use the callback provided in `setState(function|object nextState, [function callback])`:

   ```
   onClick(e) {
       this.setState({
           foobar: e.target.value
       }, this.doAfter)
   }
   doAfter() {
       console.log(`Just set FOOBAR to ${this.state.foobar}`)
   }
   ```

   Per the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html), we can rely on this method to be invoked after the state was asynchronously set.
2. Use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method:

   ```
   componentDidUpdate() {
       console.log(`Component updated: Foobar is ${this.state.foobar}`) 
   }
   ```

   Per the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html), this function will be invoked immediately after the component has rendered itself, thereby guaranteeing we have access to the latest state changes.
3. Compile all necessary `state` information in the `render()` method.

   ```
   render() {
       const compilation = {foobar: `${this.state.foobar}-bar`}
       return (
            <div>...</div>
       )
   }
   ```

   Basically, just compose the object how you'd like it before returning a JSX object from `render()`, however the first two options above might suffice better for your needs.

**Example**

http://codepen.io/mikechabot/pen/KzyVVw?editors=0011

Comment: Really good, thanks here's simple way to do it as well http://codepen.io/reggi/pen/qZVZmv?editors=0011

Comment: @ThomasReggi Yep, that's doable for most simple, synchronous cases, however since `setState` actually puts the update in a queue, you *could* encounter race conditions. From the docs: `setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.`

Comment: You could alter your pen to `this.setState(state, this.stateChanged())`, and it would have the same effect with a guarantee. Readable, and pretty! :-)

Comment: @ThomasReggi Is this answer insufficient?